# Recursive (sum of even numbers from 2 to (2 times n) ex: input : n=6, output : 2+4+6

Tags: c++, recursion

Can anyone fix this code to make it right?

I think it's almost right but the last number is correct number but followed by random number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int jumlah(int a, int b){
    if(a*2==b){
        cout<<b;
    }else{
        cout<<b<<"+";
        cout<<jumlah(a, b+2);
    }   
}

int main(){
    int a, b;
    b=2;
    cin>>a;
    jumlah(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to assume this is purely an exercise in understanding recursion, since an iterative solution would be far more concise.  One thing you should watch out is your test for finishing the recursive step.  Ask yourself what happens if the input is a negative value, zero, a _very_ large number, or invalid input like "Z".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function never returns anything, so printing the result of the recursion is undefined.

Remove the result from the function and recurse without printing.

```
void jumlah(int a, int b){
    if(a*2==b){
        cout<<b;
    }else{
        cout<<b<<"+";
        jumlah(a, b+2);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior since the function does not return anything.

Change it to:

```
int jumlah(int a, int b){

   if ( a*2 == b){
      return b;
   }

   cout << b << "+";
   return jumlah(a, b+2);
}
```

and change the call in `main` to:

```
cout << jumlah(a, b);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still not right. I really appreciate it

Comment: I try to compile it, and the last number is right but followed by random number that make it still not right